# What annotation/property defines the wsdl:definitions section of a wsdl in Jaxb?

Tags: java, wsdl, jaxb, cxf

We're using apache cxf 2.2.2 with JaxB and I need to change the wsdl:definitions name of an exported wsdl to something else.  Does anyone know how I could change it, possibly via a JAXB annotation?

Comment: Wouldn't that be via JAX-WS, not JAXB?

Comment: Yes, but you tend to end up using JAXB and JAX-WS at the same time when working with these things, so the mixup is understandable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean the `name` attribute of the `<wsdl:definitions>` element, that's set by the `serviceName` attribute of the `@WebService` annotation on your main implementation class. If you need any deeper configuration than that, you'll have to tell CXF to serve up your own custom WSDL instead of that which is derived from annotations (I've not experimented with doing that).

Comment: In the @WebService annotation there is a method called `wsdlLocation` where you can configure the location. The location is a file on the classpath relative to something in your deployment, but I don't think it is consistent across implementations (some required it in the META-INF, others not), so you would have to experiment with the location.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to give you the credit for your answer - I had forgotten the context of this question and wasn't able to test this answer's validity.  A fellow developer reported successful results, so I'll accept this - thanks.

Comment: @Metroid: Thanks for taking the trouble (in conjunction with your colleague) to check what I wrote.